# UIActivity popover: How to show only one row of symbols?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, uipopover

My app should send a picture to a server when a button is pressed. I choose to use AirDrop for this, and want the UI to be as simple as possible. Now I can exclude all activities except AirDrop, but still the popover looks quite messy:

[image]

How can I get rid of the two extra lines? They serve no purpose.

If it helps, here is the method which is called when the button is tapped:

```
- (IBAction)orderButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImage *image   = [self.detailViewController.paint extractImageFromBitmap];
    UIDevice *device = UIDevice.currentDevice;
    NSArray *items   = @[device.name, image];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items
                                                                                         applicationActivities:nil];
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                                                     UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                                                     UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                                     UIActivityTypeMessage,
                                                     UIActivityTypeMail,
                                                     UIActivityTypePrint,
                                                     UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                                     UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                                     UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                                     UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                                     UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                                     UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                                     UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;

// if iPhone
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

// if iPad
    else {
        CGFloat xPos = self.orderButton.frame.origin.x + self.orderButton.frame.size.width/2;
        CGFloat yPos = self.orderButton.frame.origin.y;
        UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityViewController];
        [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 0, 0)
                               inView:self.view
             permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                             animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't remove the more button.Its the standard in iOS 8

Comment: have you tried by changing the view size?

Comment: @T_77: Setting activityViewController.view.bounds to new values makes no difference.

Comment: My suggestion is to put some buttons like settings which customizes your app,instead of having nothing,as there is no way you can get rid of the more button.

Comment: @T_77: Also popup.popoverContentSize is ignored. Maybe I should do away with the whole popover, since I don't offer any options anyway.

Comment: did you see this:http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/ ....might be helpful!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can’t.** User can have custom 3rd party Activities there. You can’t whitelist only selected activities (e.g. AirDrop), but only blacklist some of them. Which is what you are already doing.

Comment: Too bad. It looked better before the 8.3 update when only the AirDrop line was shown, but with 8.3 it seems to be unavoidable.